# Import datasets to Google Colab directly over internet

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have found a huge dataset from an hackathon around 7 GB large. Considering too large size and internet speeds it isn't viable solution to download the data and then uploading the same to Google Drive. Isn't there a way to download the dataset directly to Google Drive to save my time and data.

Comment: Use `wget`? Where is the dataset located presently?

Comment: Actually the datasets are from competitions on HackerEarth. It's a .zip file format.

Comment: This sounds like a question for HackerEarth, in that case. I would check if they have a data set API or something similar.